# Date formatting issue when loading CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, sqldatatypes

I am loading data from CSV to SQL Server table. I have date in string data type and the date I am getting is like when I load data into table which is in string type:

```
mm/dd/yy
06/23/32
10/15/42
11/14/72
12/24/14
```

I have to convert into SQL Server standard format of date using the loaded date of string type into date format using that data which should be like:
yyyy-mm-dd
1932-06-23
1942-10-15
1972-11-14
2014-12-24

But the Issue is when I load data and do date formatting on it. Data gets wrong for dates that are less than 1950s like:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
2032-06-23
2042-10-15
1972-11-14
2014-12-24
```

Any help in this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: A key piece of information is the cutoff date for your two digit years. Is `00` = `2000` or `1900`?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new date column `new_date` and then populate it using the text dates in `old_date`, e.g.

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET new_date = CONVERT(datetime, old_date, 1);  -- e.g. old_date = 06/23/32
```

Afterwards, if you no longer require the `old_date` column, you may drop it:

```sql
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP COLUMN old_date;
```